Issue in requesting model access for amazon bedrock agent creation
I am new to AWS. I am facing this issue for requesting model access for mainly

Anthropic Claude
Cohere

I am an asia pacific Mumbai user.. I have payment info up to date with one being rupay debit card and another UPI.
Greetings from AWS Marketplace,

A payment failed due to an issue with your payment method for the following agreement on AWS account: 975050213145. The failure occurred on July, 05 2024 09:36 AM UTC due to invalid payment instrument.

Review the following details:

Product details
Product name: Claude 3 Sonnet (Amazon Bedrock Edition)
Product ID: prod-6dw3qvchef7zy

Offer details
Offer ID: offer-cft5yywmttzpm
Agreement details
Agreement ID: agmt-7uychnk2jtq678gqif021wjse

Seller details
Seller name: Anthropic

Customer details
Subscribing account ID: 975050213145

To fix the issue, follow the steps listed:

1. Confirm permissions: Before taking the following steps, ensure that you have the right permissions to view and modify payment methods for your organization. If you do not have permissions, work with your AWS Billing admin. Learn more about AWS Billing permissions in our User guide.

2. Verify agreement status: Visit the Manage subscriptions page on the AWS Marketplace console. Search for active agreements using the product name previously mentioned.

a. If there are no search results that match the product name entered, then the agreement for this product has been terminated. Skip to Step 4 to reactivate the agreement.
b. If you find a match, choose the Manage button to see the agreement ID.

ⅰ. If none of the agreement IDs on this page match the agreement ID in this notification, the agreement you attempted to create has been terminated. Skip to Step 4 to reactivate the agreement.
ⅱ. If one of the agreement IDs matches the agreement ID in this notification, the agreement you attempted to create is still active. Go to Step 3 to reattempt payment.

3. Reattempt payment for an active agreement: Visit the Payments due tab on the Payments page on the AWS Billing console to reattempt payment. Search for the failed invoice ID previously shared. Select the invoice ID on the Payment due tab, and choose the Complete payment button. Follow the instructions given to complete the payment. Learn more about how to complete due payments in our User guide.

4. Reactivate an inactive agreement: First, update your payment method so you do not face this failure again when you attempt to reactivate the agreement. Update your payment method on the Payment preferences page on the AWS Billing console. Learn about how to update your payment method in our User guide. After you update the payment method, choose the private offer link you received earlier from the seller to resubscribe to it. If you receive an error when opening the private offer link, contact the seller to generate a new private offer to which you can subscribe.

For additional help, contact AWS support.

Regards,
The AWS Marketplace Team

Amazon Web Services, Inc. is a subsidiary of Amazon.com, Inc. Amazon.com is a registered trademark of Amazon.com. This message was produced and distributed by Amazon Web Services, Inc. or its affiliates 410 Terry Ave. North, Seattle, WA 98109. © [2024], Amazon Web Services, Inc. or its affiliates. All rights reserved. Read our Privacy Notice.

